# OnChange method wont update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an onChange method that wont update my redux state. If I console.log inside the onChange, it looks right, but outside the onChange, nothing has happend and I dont understand why. I am trying to clear the errors if there are some, but nothing happens in my redux store.

Here is some code:

```
  const onChange = (e) => {
    let errors = reportIncidentState.errors || {};
    const { attr } = e.target.dataset;
    const updates = { [attr]: e.target.value };
    const clearErrors = (keys = []) => {
      errors = Object.keys(errors)
        .reduce((prev, curr) => ((typeof keys === 'string' && keys === curr)
          || keys.indexOf(curr) > -1
          ? prev : { ...prev, [curr]: errors[curr] }),
        {});
    };

    clearErrors(attr);
    switch (attr) {
      case 'partialSick':
        updates[attr] = true;
        updates.fullsick = false;
        clearErrors(['partialSick', 'fullsick']);
        break;
      case 'fullsick':
        updates[attr] = true;
        updates.partialSick = false;
        clearErrors(['partialSick', 'fullsick']);
        break;
      case 'unsureOfDate':
        updates[attr] = e.target.value;
        clearErrors(['dayofSickness', 'additionalInformation']);
        break;
      case 'hasQuit':
        updates[attr] = e.target.value;
        clearErrors(['quitDate']);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    reportIncidentUiActions.updateErrors({ errors });
    reportIncidentUiActions.updateIncidentUpdate(updates);
  };
```

Reducer:

```
    case UPDATE_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: {
          ...state.errors,
          ...action.payload.errors,
        },
        update: {
          ...state.update,
          ...action.payload.updates,
        },
      };
```

Actions:

```
export const updateErrors = ({ errors: errs }) => (
  {
    type: UPDATE_ERRORS,
    payload: { errors: errs },
  }
);
```

I expect that if a button has not been clicked, but it needs to, an error will show up, and it does. I then expect the error will be gone when the button is clicked, but it doesnt go away. And in my redux store, the error is still there..

Comment: Perhaps it'd be helpful to include some code related to redux, i.e. action creators and reducers. Can you update your question to include all relevant code, the issue and reproducible steps, and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just because here:

```
return {
    ...state,
    errors: {
      ...state.errors,
      ...action.payload.errors,
    },
```

you are *merging* the existing errors with the cleared errors - there's no way for it to remove an item.

Depending on your use case, you could either just do:

```
errors: action.payload.errors,
```

Or you can add something like:

```
case REMOVE_ERRORS:
  const errors = { ...state.errors };
  action.payload.errors.forEach((error) => {
      delete errors[error];
  });
  return {
    ...state,
    errors
  };
```

and then trigger that when removing errors.

Comment: what can I do insted?  Im pretty new to this.